# Компиляция скрипта на Java SE7 в Sublime Text 2

Tags: java, компиляция, sublime-text

Как скомпилировать скрипт на Java SE7 в Sublime Text 2?

Как там настроить компилятор под Java?

Comment: Кастрированный платный vim это плохая ide для java. Попробуйте лучше Eclipse или NetBeans. Ну или  оригинальный vim или emacs если хочется хардкора.

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1685
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=759
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4805
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: Ну и конечно на Java не пишутся скрипты, поэтому сделать это невозможно так как не понятно, где этот скрипт взять? ))

Comment: а чем Вас не устраивает Eclipse или NetBeans? Вообще не вижу смысле юзать Sublime под java...

Comment: Если человеку хэлловорды ваять, то sublime самое оно. А нетбинс тут будет слишком. А Эклипс... с ним ещё нужно понять, что у него модель сохранения проекта немного необычная на первый взгляд.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я все таки  рекомендую использовать eclipse/idea/emacs/vim. Но если сильно-сильно хочется...

В принципе ничего не нужно настраивать - все уже есть. После того, как откроете свой жава файл, просто зайдите в меню Tools-> Build System и убедитесь, что там выбрано JavaC. Если нет - выбирайте.
Все, теперь можно жать `Ctrl+B` и саблим запустит javac  для компиляции.

Установить жаву конечно же нужно. И настроить, что бы она была в путях. На моем ноуте под Fedora все завелось сразу.

Answer (score 0):

В меню выберите Tools-> Build System -> New Build System, после чего откроется новая вкладка, куда нужно вставить следующий текст:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
    "shell": true,
    "path": "c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Параметр "path" указывает путь к JDK, если он у вас отличается, измените на свой. Либо можете удалить всю строку, если у вас путь прописан в системной переменной.

Теперь нажмите комбинацию "ctrl + s" и сохраните файл настроек выполнения под любым именем, к примеру "JavaCompileRun".

Последним шагом выбираем в меню пункт Tools-> Build System -> JavaCompileRun и дальше, при нажатии "ctrl + b" открытый файл c java-кодом будет выполнятся.